# How do I use another java project in my code?

Tags: java, git, eclipse

I am currently using the Eclipse IDE and want to import an external java project so that I can use it in something I am working on. I downloaded the directory of icePDF, found [here](http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icepdf/branches/icepdf-6.2.5/), and would like to use the java class file "[SwingViewBuilder.java](http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icepdf/branches/icepdf-6.2.5/icepdf/viewer/src/org/icepdf/ri/common/SwingViewBuilder.java)" that is found in the directory I linked at "/icepdf/branches/icepdf-6.2.5/icepdf/viewer/src/org/icepdf/ri/common". I have tried some basic things like importing the folder itself, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest using a dependency management tool like Maven or Gradle to download this dependency and any other dependencies you may have into your project for you.

Here is the maven getting started guide: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/

And here is the maven dependency for you to add to your pom.xml file: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.icepdf.os/icepdf-viewer/6.2.2

If you specifically need version 6.2.5, you will need to build the icePDF project yourself and configure your class path to use it as a dependency.